# How do I set the scsi host number for a disk in virtualbox using vboxmanage?

Tags: virtualbox, udev, scsi

I am loading CentOS 7.4 on a virtual box vm and specifying 30 disks. The 30 disks are customized using vboxmanage as follows:

`v.customize ["createmedium", "disk",
   "--filename", disk,
   "--size", "100",
   "--format", "VDI",
   "--variant", "fixed"
]
['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', i, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disk]
['setextradata', :id, "VBoxInternal/Devices/ahci/0/Config/Port#{i}/SerialNumber", "081118FC1221NCJ6G8#{id}"]`

This configuration works well because I can pin the serial number of the disk such that it is the same no matter how many times I destroy / bring up the virtual machine. Unfortunately, I can't say the same for the devpath. For example, udev shows the following upon startup for /dev/sda:

`DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sda`

The values in this path seem to be variable for `pci`, `ata`, `host`, and `target`. I was hoping I could set some extra data on the disk (similar to how the serial number is being set with vboxmanage above) but I haven't found a way to do this. Is this possible?

Regards,

Will

Comment: There should be an entry in `/dev/disk/by-id/`, in your case, something like `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_081118FC1221NCJ6G8xx`.  Though, it's possible that you've taken too many bytes of the serial number up with `081118...` to allow for uniqueness?

Comment: Hi @MikeAndrews, /dev/disk/by-id does indeed contain each of the disks as expected, but the values for "ata", "host", and "target" are variable whenever I destroy the box and bring it back up. For now I will continue to treat them as variable as I cannot find a way to configure the vm such that the scsi host is always fixed.